# Why this sql returns like that?

Tags: sql, hibernate

i have below sql

```
SELECT SUM(amount) from CustomerPayment where date like '%2013' GROUP BY TYPE
```

in Type column there are two choice one them is BANK and the other one is CASH

I want to sum these seperately. For ex: bank is totally 500 and cash is 400

However above sql does not sum the records. Instead, it returns first record of bank and cash records. Why?

Comment: Please paste your table data here

Comment: Nothing wrong with your query except that `like` - use `year(date) == 2013`. It works fine for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7c1c90/3

Answer (score 0):

I would say try and add type to the sql query. Then it has a visible representation of the type you wish to group by.

```
 SELECT SUM(amount), TYPE from CustomerPayment where date like '%2013' GROUP BY TYPE
```

Comment: gives this error at org.hibernate.hql.classic.PathExpressionParser.token(PathExpressionParser.java:1‌​30) at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:28) at org.hibernate.hql.classic.SelectParser.token(SelectParser.java:176) at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:86)

Comment: I can't find where the mistake might be in the sql statement. Might it be related with the data you try to enter? If this is the case, that might explain why with the current given info, we're not able to see the problem.

Comment: i use hibernate may be it is different  in hibernate .s

Answer (score 0):

can you try using year(date)=2013, as data is not there so I am guessing if 'like' function is not letting group by to perform its functionality properly.

Comment: you should paste data first

Answer (score 0):

If your date field has a datatype of `Date` or `DateTime` then the LIKE operator won't work.

For date comparisons use date functions.

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM CustomerPayment
WHERE YEAR(date) = 2013
GROUP BY TYPE
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year

Answer (score -1):

include TYPE col also

```
SELECT TYPE, SUM(amount) from CustomerPayment where date like '%2013' GROUP BY TYPE
```

Comment: givez this error at org.hibernate.hql.classic.PathExpressionParser.token(PathExpressionParser.java:130)
 at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ParserHelper.parse(ParserHelper.java:28)
 at org.hibernate.hql.classic.SelectParser.token(SelectParser.java:176)
 at org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClauseParser.token(ClauseParser.java:86)

Comment: Adding a field to the SELECT component won't make a difference when handling the GROUP BY or the WHERE conditions